# How to upload a htaccess file with htpasswd?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to protect my directory with apache password protection, basically their is a subdirectory named reg in my /var/www folder. now, I have .htaccess in the `/var/www/reg` folder and the content is

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd 
AuthName "Please Log In" 
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

and a .htpasswd file in /var/www folder and the content is 
 `xyz:AFm9t1CfobrkA`
but when I try to access the folder typing `localhost/reg` no pop up box appear asking for username and password. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is your apache accepting .htaccess files? Have you tried it with the relative path ../.htpasswd?

Comment: Probably need to set an AllowOverride on your reg folder in your apache configuration

Comment: Correct, especially in this case AllowOverride AuthConfig

Comment: Where do I put set the allow override option? In the .htaccess file? that didn't work.

Comment: You need to put it in the `<directory>` container for the directory that your htaccess file is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have .htaccess file like this:

```
AuthUserFile /data/www/.../http-users
AuthType Basic
AuthName "private"

require user cf
```

And it works. What you could do:

- Detect the possible cause by looking into the error log. In many cases you have access to it even on hosting environments
- Make sure `AllowOverride AuthConfig` is set. You cannot set it in `.htaccess`, you must do it in the server configuration file. In a hosting environment, you have to ask your hosting provider.
- Not very likely, but it could be the dot - try to rename the `.htpasswd` file to `htpasswd`
- Its definitelly not caused by missing the `<directory>` container as noted in the discussion

Comment: apache default sever conf does not allow htaccess, I changed it from /etc/apache2